# React native boton de history back

Tags: reactjs

Buenas tardes tengo una aplicación en `react native` y necesito hacer un botón de **history back**, alguien sabe como hacer este botón? Es decir, abro un enlace de mi página principal y darle regreser a la pantalla que abra con el comando de javascript history.back es posible?

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré lo que buscaba, en realidad era mas simple de lo que parece. Lo encontré en un script en internet. Lo marque en negrita lo que necesitaba.

```
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    /* 2. Get the param, provide a fallback value if not available */
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
    const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value');

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
        <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details... again"
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.push('Details', {
              itemId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            })}
        />
        <Button
          title="Go to Home"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        />
        **<Button
          title="Go back"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />**
      </View>
    );
  }
```

}

Gracias igualmente